# iOS Cordova PhoneGap barcodescanner orientation

Tags: ios, cordova, barcode-scanner, uiinterfaceorientation

We have a Sencha Touch app which launches the Cordova PhoneGap Zxing barcode scanner. This problem primarily manifests itself in iOS.

The barcode scanner launches in Portrait mode irrespective of what the device orientation is. That is ok for us. It is not a problem. However, if we have the device in landscape mode and launch our app, it launches in landscape mode. Now if the barcode scanner is launched, and then the scanner completes it’s scanning, and closes, the app is forced into portrait mode, even though the device orientation is in landscape mode. This results in a Black/Grey band on the right side of the screen, since the app thinks the device is in portrait mode, even though the device is actually still in landscape mode. (See image here http://imgur.com/8BOEdeX)

It appears as if the scanner plugin, forces the device and therefore the app to think it is in portrait mode and does not reset it to it’s actual orientation even after it is closed.

Any ideas how to get the device and the app to get reoriented (and therefore resized) once the scanner closes?